# Create structure for every page

Tags: tables, logos, structure

I would like to like to create the following structure and place it on the top of the pages 
[image]

Could you please suggest me the most appropriate way to make it? The height need to be configurable also.

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the following could serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}

\setlength{\headheight}{32pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{S{p{8cm}}X}
       \cellcolor{green} Text & \cellcolor{orange} Text\\
       \end{tabularx}
       }
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
some content
\newpage
other content
\end{document}
```